# Map data structure for Google Charts

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I make a call to my backend where I read a JSON file, and return it as an array. I do this to make it easier to handle, this is the code

```
let url = `/api/some-url/${this.$route.params.id}`;

axios.get(url).then(data => {
    console.log(data.data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
});
```

The output of the console.log looks something like this.

```
(7) [Array(345), Array(5), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(4)]
    0: (345) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
    1: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    2: [721]
    3: [3201]
    4: ["2012-01-08"]
    5: ["2019-05-02"]
    6: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

For now I am interested in the array at element 6.  This looks like the following

```
6: Array(4)
    0: {Category: "cat1", Count: 11}
    1: {Category: "cat2", Count: 24}
    2: {Category: "cat3", Count: 52}
    3: {Category: "cat4", Count: 57}
```

Now from what I understand, Google Charts requires the first row of the array to be the column names, and each other row the data.  Something like

```
let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Year', 'Asia'],
   ['2012',  900],
   ['2013',  1000],
]);
```

So in my case I am thinking it needs to be something alone the lines of

```
let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Category', 'Count'],
   ['cat1',  11],
   ['cat2',  24],
   ['cat3',  52],
   ['cat4',  57]
]);
```

What would be the best way to achieve this format based on my initial data?  Also, there are about 3 elements from the initial array I have that needs there data formatted like this, would I do them individually or someway together?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys`, `Object.values` and `Array.prototype.map` functions in order to make this conversion function:

```
function JSONtoGoogleData(src) {
  return [Object.keys(src[0])].
    concat(
      src.map(
        obj => Object.values(obj)
      )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` to modify each element of the returned array, and `map` with `Object.values` for the nested arrays. The first line is a conditional which avoids errors by checking which items are arrays and which aren't.

```
let changed = data.data.map(e => {
    if (!e.map) return e;
    return e.map(Object.values);
}).filter(Boolean);
```